# Entity Framework and one-to-many relationship

Tags: entity-framework, entity-relationship

I'm trying to set up one-to-many relationship with EF.

*A user can have many (or none) access records.*

- User primary key is userid
- UserAccess foreign key is userid

So my set up is the following:

```
public class User
{
    // ...
    public virtual ICollection<UserAccess> UserAccess { get; set; }
}

public class UserAccess
{
    // ...
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

And my code in *UserAccessMap*:

```
this.HasMany(t => t.UserAccess).WithMany().Map(m => m.MapLeftKey("USERID"));
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You were doing many to many relationship, see the configuration pattern.

```
HasMany.. WithMany..
```

The one to many configuration should be either `HasMany.. WithRequired/WithOptional..` or `HasRequired/HasOptional.. WithMany..`.

In `UserAccessMap`

```
HasRequired(t => t.User).WithMany(x => x.UserAccess).Map(x=> x.MapKey("USERID"));
```

Or in `UserMap`

```
HasMany(t => t.UserAccess).WithRequired(x => x.User).Map(x=> x.MapKey("USERID"));
```